# Android Error : mGoogleApiClient cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, android-activity

I m encountering an error while trying to make an Android app with location and maps.

Here is my `MainActivity.java` file

```
package com.example.myapp;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import  com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    buildGoogleApiClient();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }
   protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
       mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
          .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
          .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
          .addApi(LocationServices.API)
          .build();
    }

}
```

it shows mGoogleApiClient cannot be resolved to a variable error.
Also same error is there for addConnectionCallbacks as well.

Please help me resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: provide logcat message

Comment: how do i get logcat message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See doc for [addOnConnectionFailedListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder.html#addConnectionCallbacks%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks%29) and [OnConnectionFailedListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder.html#addOnConnectionFailedListener%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener%29). If you implement both `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` and       `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener` in your Activity then you can easily be able to pass `this` to build GoogleApiClient.Builder object.

And make sure to declare mGoogleApiClient beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't declare your mGoogleApiClient variable declare it as-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient ;
```